# What's the proper way of passing a ref to a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a ref of a component to another component. Since [string refs are being deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs) I'm using callback refs.

So I have something similar to this:

```
<One ref={c => this.one = c}/>
<Two one={this.one}/>
```

The problem is that whenever I try to access `this.props.one` inside `Two` I get `undefined`.

I have even tried this on `Two`:

```
componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(this.props.one);
    },5000)
}
```

It seems the problem is that when the prop is created, the ref doesn't exist yet since it's created once `One` is mounted. But I don't know how to "refresh" the props on `Two` to get the ref to the mounted component.

So what's the proper way of passing a ref to another component?

**Edit**

Some users have suggested to encapsulate that logic in a higher component, which in itself renders those other child components.

The problem with that approach is that you can't create reusable logic and you have to repeat the same logic over and over in those encapsulating components.

Let's say you want to create a generic `<Form>` component which encapsulates the submit logic to your store, error checking, etc. And you do something like this:

```
<Form>
    <Input/>
    <Input/>
    <Input/>
    <Input/>
    <SubmitButton/> 
</Form>
```

In this example `<Form>` can't access the instances (and methods) of the children since `this.props.children` doesn't return those instances. It returns some list of pseudo components.

So how can you check if a certain `<Input/>` has detected a validation error without passing a ref?

You have to encapsulate those components in another component with the validation logic. For example in `<UserForm>`. But since each form is different the same logic has to be copied in `<CategoryForm>`, `<GoupForm>`, etc. This is terribly inefficient which is why I want to encapsulate the validation logic in `<Form>` and pass references of the `<Input>` components to `<Form>`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're trying to do this but it's probably better to try to consider how to pass around the data that you want instead. React favours rendering based from data, not from the results of rendering, so it is best for you to position your data at a higher level so that it may be passed down all of the components that need it.

Comment: Because I need to pass the instance of the component so that I can call its methods. Using callback refs is not against the rules: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Comment: Pier, see my answer if you really want to pass around the ref - however another thing you should consider is hoisting the functions up to the parent component and passing pointers to those functions to both children.  That matches the react methodology and results in much easier to test code.

Comment: Hey Carl, I have updated my question with more info about the problem I'm trying to solve and why I want to use refs.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  For that particular use-case I suggest using `context` which was designed to solve exactly this problem.  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any example on how context would be used for this problem?

Comment: I spoke too soon, context doesn't solve your issue. Context allows children to reference typed "properties" from higher up in the tree without specifically being passed those properties.  It can help with writing generic components. The "reacty" way to do this is to move form state out of the Input components. Consider having a class which represents your generic data and validation logic - this class encapsulates a single Input component but is passed down from the parent. Since the form has a list of these instances, it can ignore the child components themselves.

Comment: But how can you pass the list of these instances to the form without refs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120562/discussion-between-carl-sverre-and-pier).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In general the "ref" feature is an anti-pattern in React.  It exists to enable side-effect driven development, however in order to benefit the most from the React way of programming you should try to avoid "refs" if possible.

As for your particular issue, passing a child a ref to it's sibling is a chicken vs. egg scenario.  The ref callback is fired when the child is mounted, not during render which is why your example doesn't work.  One thing you can try is pushing the ref into state and then reading from state into the other child.  So:

```
<One ref={c => !this.state.one && this.setState({ one: c })}/>
<Two one={this.state.one}/>
```

Note: without the `!this.state.one` this will cause an infinite loop.

Here is a codepen example of this working (look at the console to see the sibling ref logged): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbqvRA

Comment: I updated the code to only show the solution that includes `!this.state.one` which does work.  The reason setState is needed is that the parent component needs to be rendered *after* the ref callback fires.  Also, this may cause very weird behavior since each time React renders it will technically construct a new ref object.

Comment: I'm accepting this since it does answer the question.

Comment: Guys, I this is not working now. Check the fiddle and see that there is an error saying Maximum call stack exceeded. Any other ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Here is an updated version that prevents the loop by only assigning the ref once.  Note - this is a very unsafe thing to do in your code.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vePGmY

Comment: Also notice in my comment how I talk about the infinite loop prevention.  "Note: without the !this.state.one this will cause an infinite loop."

Comment: @CarlSverre If this is anti-pattern, then what's the workaround?

Comment: Honestly the workaround is to avoid using ref's at all.  Ways to avoid this in order of preference: leveraging props, extracting state into a third party store, leveraging context.

Comment: Isn't calling setState inside render() more of an antipattern than using refs?

Comment: This whole idea is an anti-pattern. The initial question was asking how to pass a ref of one child to another. To do this you need to grab the ref during one render cycle, schedule a second render (setState) and then pass the captured ref to the other child. Hence the infinite loop possibility in the discussion above.

Comment: A better solution in React 16 and above is answered below by Kevin.groat

Answer (score 13):

This is now much simpler using the [new ref api](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) (available since React 16 - thanks to perilandmishap for pointing that out).

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.oneRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <One ref={this.oneRef} />
        <Two ref={this.oneRef} />
      </React.Fragment>
    }
  }
}
```

You would consume the prop in `<Two/>` like:

```js
this.props.one.current
```

A few things of note with this approach:

The ref will be an object with a `current` property.  That property will be `null` **until the element/component is mounted**.  Once it's mounted, it will be the instance of `<One/>`.  It *should* be safe to reference it once `<Two />` is mounted.

Once the `<One />` instance is unmounted, the `current` property on the ref returns to being `null`.

Comment: Yeah, new refs are great lovely, but heads up, this is only available in > react 16

Comment: It works only when `<One />` is initialised before `<Two/>`. For example if you make `<Two/>` a child of `<One/>` then `Two` will always receive `null` even inside it's `componentDidMount`. You need to tell `Two` somehow that `One` has mounted.

Answer (score 7):

In general, if you need to pass a reference to something that may not be set at call time, you can pass a lambda instead:

```
<One ref={c => this.one = c}/>
<Two one={() => this.one}/>
```

and then reference it as

```
this.props.one()
```

If it has been set when you call it, you'll get a value. Before that, you'll get `undefined` (assuming it hasn't otherwise been initialized).

It bears noting that you won't necessarily re-render when it becomes available, and I would expect it to be `undefined` on the first render. This is something that using state to hold your reference does handle, but you won't get more than one re-render.

Given all that, I would recommend moving whatever code was using the ref to `One` in `Two` up into the component that is rendering `One` and `Two`, to avoid all the issues with both this strategy, and the one in @Carl Sverre's answer.

Comment: Putting things in state definitely works, but there are things that aren't a good match for storing in state (large complex js objects), and this was the only approach that worked

Answer (score 0):

```
<One ref={c => this.one = c}/>
<Two one={this.one}/>
```

```
class One extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <div ref={this.props.one}/>;
  }
}

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <One {...props} {...ref.current} />
));
```

The `ref` prop is for elements *with `forwardRef` in its own file*.

```
class IndexApp extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.one = React.createRef();
  }
  render (){
    return <div>
      <One ref={{current:{one:this.one}}}/>
      <Two ref={{current:{one:this.one}}}/>
    </div>;
  }
}
```