# Pass down a canvas ref through Context in React

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I am working on implementing some canvas rendering by using Components.  I have the following Component which attempts to layout the canvas to the page, and have subcomponents in the `Stage` component draw to its context.

I need a reference to the canvas elements that my `Renderer` component is rendering.  So I ask for the ref in the JSX, and set it on my component when I get it.  I'm also using React context, so that all the children components can access this canvas reference.  The problem I'm having is that it seems `getChildContext` is called before the canvas ref is assigned and so all the children component access an undefined canvas and no drawing is done.

```
export default class Renderer extends React.Component {

    static childContextTypes = {
        canvas: PropTypes.object
    };

    getChildContext() {
        console.log("get child context")
        return { canvas: this.canvas };         
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="CanvasHolder" key={0}>
            <canvas className="MainCanvas" ref= { 
                canvas => { 
                    this.canvas = canvas 
                    console.log("got ref");

                }
                } />
            <Stage />
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't come across this issue yet, but I'll try to help. Looks like the `context` is set before the `ref` is attributed. A workaround would be to do a `setState` inside the `ref` function, so  the component renders again, this time with the correct reference.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864033/react-whats-the-proper-way-of-passing-a-ref-to-a-prop

Comment: i tried that and it resulted in an infinite loop, as setState retriggers a render call, and the render call is where i'm setting the ref.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the `ref` only after in `componentDidMount` (after it is rendered). But the parent component is considered rendered only when all of its children are rendered. So children can't access parent's `ref` before it is rendered. Instead of returning `canvas` ref directly, try to pass custom function `getCanvas()` instead:

```
getCanvas = () => {
  return this.canvas
}
```

And then in your children component call this function to retrieve `canvas` ref.

Comment: i also tried using context to pass down the ref.  the problem with that is getChildContext is called only once before the ref callback is invoked.

Comment: Yes, but I suggest to pass function via context, not ref. `getChildContext() {
        return { getCanvas: this.getCanvas };         
    }`

Comment: With ref defined with useRef hook `const canvasRef = useRef(null);`, the function to pass to child is  `const getCanvas = () => { return canvasRef.current }`