# react-popper: re-position using scheduleUpdate

Tags: javascript, popper.js, react-popper

I'm using [React-popper](https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper) to show a date picker element after clicking a button.

## JSX

```
<Manager>
    <Reference>
        {({ ref }) => (
            <button ref={ref} onClick={this.onDateRangeBtnClick}>click to show</button>
        )}
    </Reference>
    {ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <Popper placement="auto-end" >
            {({ ref, style, placement, arrowProps, scheduleUpdate }) => (
                <div className={`dayPickerOverlay ${this.state.showDatePicker ? "" : "hidden"}`} ref={ref} style={style} data-placement={placement}>
                    <DateRangePicker />
                </div>
            )}
        </Popper>,
        document.querySelector('#root')
    )}
</Manager>
```

When `onDateRangeBtnClick` is called after the button was clicked, I want to re-position the Popper element by calling `scheduleUpdate` method, but I do not know how to approach this.

How can I expose that specific `scheduleUpdate` to be called within the `onDateRangeBtnClick` or alternatively how can I conditionally call a function (`scheduleUpdate` for this matter) within JSX itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would split the popper part into its own component and take advantage of the React lifecycle hooks.

Inside `componentDidUpdate` you can check if the `open` state changed, and trigger the `scheduleUpdate` accordingly.

```
// PopperElement.js
export default class PopperElement extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.open && this.props.open !== prevProps.open) {
      this.props.scheduleUpdate();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`dayPickerOverlay ${this.state.showDatePicker ? "" : "hidden"}`} ref={ref} style={style} data-placement={placement}>
        <DateRangePicker />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// App.js
<Manager>
  <Reference>
    {({ ref }) => (
      <button ref={ref} onClick={this.onDateRangeBtnClick}>click to show</button>
    )}
  </Reference>
  {ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <Popper placement="auto-end">
      {({ ref, style, placement, arrowProps, scheduleUpdate }) => (
        <PopperElement open={this.state.open} scheduleUpdate={scheduleUpdate} />
      )}
    </Popper>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
  )}
</Manager>
```

If you prefer a more concise approach, I think I'd use `react-powerplug` this way:

```
import { Manager, Popper, Reference } from 'react-popper';
import { State } from 'react-powerplug';

const App = () => (
  <Manager>
    <Popper>
      {({ ref, style, scheduleUpdate }) => (
        <State initial={{ open: false }} onChange={scheduleUpdate}>
          {({ state, setState }) => (
            <Fragment>
              <Reference>
                {({ ref }) => (
                  <button
                    ref={ref}
                    onClick={() => setState({ open: true }})
                  >click to show</button>
                )}
              </Reference>
              {open && <YourContent ref={ref} style={style} />}
            </Fragment>
          )}
        </State>
      )}
    </State>
  </Manager>
);
```

I avoided to repeat the `React.createPortal` part for conciseness, it should be in place of `YourContent`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! Another great example why React is horrible way to build apps. So much unnecessary files and code are needed simply to call a function on state change..

Comment: I added an alternative approach

Comment: It appears your first example cannot work since `ref` cannot be passed to child component. [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38864033/104380)

Comment: You just have to give it a different name. Like `innerRef` or use the new forwardRef API of React

Comment: I have been tinkering with this for the past 4 hours now

Comment: @FezVrasta: Your example depends on the Popper updating. Is there a way to call `scheduleUpdate` if the reference element changes but the Popper does not? I've run into a case where `componentDidUpdate` doesn't get called, so the positioning doesn't change.